# Is it possible to mock afMongo's MongoClient or ConnectionManager?

Tags: mongodb, fantom

I am using [afMongo](http://repo.status302.com/doc/afMongo/) for accessing a Mongo DB from a [Fantom](http://fantom.org) web app and I'm wondering if it is possible to mock the MongoClient or the ConnectionManager so that the Test classes don't need a Mongo DB running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is *no*.

The long answer is *yes*, but you need to write the mock yourself and it's quite low level.

`Connection` is the thing to mock because it's a mixin. Internally, afMongo uses [MockMongoConnection](https://bitbucket.org/AlienFactory/afmongo/src/efe7669e3f4cc3bee7b379a59e90cbf1299d65b2/test/unit-tests/MockMongoConnection.fan?at=default) so you could try using / extending that.

Typical usage would be:

```java
mmc    = MockMongoConnection()
conMgr = ConnectionManagerLocal(mmc, ``)
mmc.reset.reply(...your map obj...)
```

You're probably better off wrapping your Mongo calls in your own DAO service and mocking that.